# Retrieving JSON data in D3 using d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, d3.js

I am trying to retrieve [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json) JSON data and display it in a D3 project and can't seem to get d3.json to do this.

I've tried this:

```
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);

  })
```

I've also tried saving it locally and loading it in like this:

```
d3.json("cyclist-data.json", function(error, d){
    console.log(d);
  });
```

I've also tried saving the url into a variable and passing the variable to the d3.json function like this:

```
  var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json';

d3.json(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);

  })
```

None of this works. How can I successfully pull the JSON data and console.log it?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you see any errors? What does it log to your console? And, very important, what version of D3 are you using?

Comment: None of them output anything. And it's version 5. What's the proper way to load in JSON in this version?

Comment: In v5 the API has changed. Please have a look at the question I marked this as a duplicate of.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. Thank you.